# What could cause a page to stop from appearing on StumbleUpon?

Tags: traffic, content, social-media, web-traffic, website-promotion

I've got a page that got some attention from stumbleupon (~100 likes and ~2700 views), and then suddenly 'disappeared' - stumbles stopped completely.

The page content wasn't changed in any way. Looking at StumbleUpon's [content guidelines](http://www.stumbleupon.com/ads/help/content_guidelines), no relevant info was found.

What could cause this? Is there any action a webmaster can do to retain stumbles?

**update:**

The response from StumbleUpon [support forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/stumbleupon_help_center/topics/page-got-100-likes-and-2700-views-then-disappeared):

```
Your account is fully functional. Your page is not blocked. 
If you are seeking guaranteed traffic, then [...] StumbleUpon 
Ads is designed to do that for you.
```

Is it possible that SU is purposely blocking pages in order to push users into buying ads?

Comment: Does StumbleUpon have a forum or support for this?

Comment: Why are you expecting constant traffic from SU? Doesn't it work like Reddit where it's popular for a short time, then drops off?

Comment: The honest answer is that  I'm not sure and maybe it does work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is little bit too broad because there could be a numerous reasons for this, but I'll try to narrow down.

**You are banned.**

From this article [**here**](http://websitehostreview.com/why-isnt-stumbleupon-sending-my-site-any-web-traffic/) you can see many reasons for account being removed / banned etc.

If your stumbles are not showing up in your SU profile, your account might be banned. Here are some possible reasons for banning in SU.

> - Too many different SU usernames voting from the same IP address.
> - Reciprocal voting activity, based on tracked patterns or published       confirmation (i.e., a blog post or social media campaign suggesting
>     potential reciprocal voting activities)
> - Too many users voting on the same story and coming from the same       referring URL – e.g., from a forum listing.
> - Misuse of the ‘send’ button. The SU browser tool bar has a Send       button that lets you message your SU friends on some content you’d
>     like them to look at. If you you’re only sending them your stories,
>     votes for your site could be discounted.
> - Complaints. This is a pretty broad area, and there can be any sort of    complaint from other users which might cause you problems on SU.

StumbleUpon is wonderful for traffic. Try to contact them directly to see what's up with your account.

EDIT:

But, from my experiences, I know that in first week or two I get many views. Eventually I'm getting lower and lower and lower views. You need to put fresh and new articles over and over and over again, and that's it. This is not unusuall. I thought that you were banned. But, this is (from my experience) normal behaviour. It's stumble upon dude. I don't use it so often as I used to do. I don't know what else to say about this matter. It site for generating traffic.

Comment: Seems like this is not the case. See edit

Comment: You are not banned and you don't see your content?

Comment: I do see my content normally - but the page that was getting the stumbles and likes on a daily basis stopped getting any exposure. The thing is it got 100 likes and 2700 in a few days, with a stable traffic, and than just stopped at once, which looked like an unnatural behavior.

Comment: And the account is confirmed not to be banned in any way

Comment: That is not unnatural behaviour. It happens with sites like these. I don't know any case that it didn't happen. Is it back again?

Comment: no. I guess I'm confused since I see pages with less likes and a lot more views, and thought exposure is given according to user ratings.

Comment: So, what's your question? it's all ok, you are concerned about views?

Comment: If it's a kown fact that stumbles on stumbleupon are not continious, and that it's normal for moderately succesful pages to stop getting views completely, that's answering my question.

Comment: Do you know how it works? Here's a great link to read about it. https://www.quicksprout.com/2012/04/24/the-secret-to-getting-highly-targeted-traffic-from-stumbleupon/

Comment: But, from my experiences, I know that in first week or two I get many views. Eventually I'm getting lower and lower and lower views. You need to put fresh and new articles over and over and over again, and that's it. This is not unusuall. I thought that you were banned. But, this is (from my experience) normal behaviour. It's stumble upon dude. I don't use it so often as I used to do. I don't know what else to say about this matter. It site for generating traffic.

Comment: Is it ok now or what? What are your stats as for today or day before?

Comment: It's still off the grid. I guess I just didn't understand the way it works with StumbleUpon, Thank you for the explanation. Maybe edit your last comment as an answer so I can accept it for future users

Comment: Ok. I've did that now. Good luck in future with stumble upon!

Comment: I would have edit it a bit so that users doesn't think they are banned right away

Comment: Great edit. Cheers!